# I want a new modified copy of a list of linked hash map in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this list and want to create a new copy of modified list without the same old reference.

list :

```
[
{
player: {playerID: 1037510, firstName: Brad, lastName: Ausmus, role: B}, 
buntingForAHit: 0,
 pitchouts: 0, 
usingRelievers: 0,
 usingClosers: 0
},

 {
player: {playerID: 1075714, firstName: Rich, lastName: Becker, role: B},
 buntingForAHit: 0, 
pitchouts: 0, 
usingRelievers: 0, 
usingClosers: 0
}
]
```

I have shown only two element in a list but there are almost 20 elements.
Each element in the list is in the form of Map.

Now from this given list I want to make a new modified copy of it with the new reference. so that old list is not modified.
The new list will have player ID outside of player and there will be no player .for eg:
new list will be

```
[
{ 
playerID: 1037510,
buntingForAHit: 0,
 pitchouts: 0, 
usingRelievers: 0,
 usingClosers: 0
},

{
playerID: 1075714,
 buntingForAHit: 0, 
pitchouts: 0, 
usingRelievers: 0, 
usingClosers: 0
}

]
```

so simply I want to extract playerID from player and then delete player from the list.and than add player id to each element in the list.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```dart
var newList = oldList.map((player) => {
   "playerID": player["player"]["playerID"],
"buntingForAHit": player["buntingForAHit"],
 "pitchouts": player["pitchouts"], 
"usingRelievers": player["usingRelievers"],
 "usingClosers": player["usingClosers"]
}
).toList();
```

Comment: thanks ,that works. I was trying to remove the player and then adding it again all the time.